# Contour integral around a branch cut with a pole at the end of the cut

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration, branch-cuts

I would like to evaluate the following complex integral,
\begin{equation}
\oint_C \frac{f(z)}{z} \, \log z \, \text{d}z\,,
\end{equation}
where $f(z) = a + b/z - \bar{b}z $ with $a,b \in \mathbb{C}$. The contour $C$ is a circle surrounding a line joining the origin $0$ and one of the roots of $f$, denoted $z_+ =\frac{a-\sqrt{a^2+4|b|^2}}{2\bar{b}}$. So the circle encloses a first branch cut, and there are two other branch points (the second root of $f$, $z_-$, and the point at infinity) outside the circle.

One problem (for me at least) seems to be that the point $z=0$ is a pole of the integrand and also lies at the end of the inner cut, so one cannot directly integrate along the cut.

My knowledge of contour integral is rather limited once one cannot use residue theorem (nor residue at infinity), and I would make great use of some help on the procedure to follow to deal with this kind of integrals.

Comment: Another problem is that $\ln(z)$ isn't defined on contours surrounding the origin.

Comment: @LukasRollier, yes indeed, this is why I join the two branch points inside the circle with a segment and take this segment as my branch cut. The point $z_-$ and the point at infinity are also joined as a second branch cut, but the circle $C$ can be taken such that it does not cross any of the cuts, so everything is well defined. Or maybe I missunderstood your comment.